# Building an PTP TSU + RTC module

Tags: fpga, rtc, synchronization

I want to build a simple Precision Time Protocol Timestamp Unit and Real-Time clock (PTP TSU + RTC module). My accuracy requirement is +-50ns.

I found a good opencore ha1588 which fits for RTL part.

In software PTPd part, I have to build a simple one for supporting PTP slave only.

I learn PTP that the time adjustment offset is ((T2-T1)-(T4-T3))/2 which is simple enough for me.

However, the frequency adjustment part (syncing the slave clock from master) is unknown to me.

Does anyone know the formula of frequency adjustment to fpga real time clock counter?
I believe it is depending on at least the 'adjustment time offset'.

Comment: have you looked at the open hardware that was designed within CERN's White Rabbit efforts?

Comment: pardon that I don't know the acronyms but wouldn't you measure the time between two packets according to the sender, and then according to your own clock, then you can adjust your clock frequency accordingly? You can apply some filtering to reduce jitter

Comment: hm, that is a way if you can live with high clock jitter. Usually, in an IEEE1588 network, you also apply physical layer tricks (synchronous ethernet) that allow the slave clocks to be frequency-synchronized to the master clock at a far higher accuracy, by recovering the master clock frequency directly from the Ethernet physical layer symbols. "White Rabbit" is an application suite built atop of Synchronous Ethernet + IEEE1588 that allows the large particle accelerator measurement devices to have a good common frequency and time. (Wikipedia's your friend here)